# Class changes required for mocking for Unit Test Cases

Tags: c++, googlemock

We have a class that has methods which implements threads:

```
class ThreadPool
{
//Thread creation and invocation
int Create();
};
```

Another class that embeds a ThreadPool in it

```
class Service
{
public:
ThreadPool mThreadPool;
int start();
}

int Service::start()
{
mThreadPoll.Create();
.......
}
```

Cause of the above design pattern I am unable to mock my Service class.

I am trying to write an interface class to ThreadPool and use it in Service class:

```
class InterfaceThreadPool
{
virtual int Create () = 0;
};

class ThreadPool : public InterfaceThreadPool
{
int Create () override;
};
```

My idea is to create an interface class ThreadPoolImpl which I can use it in my Service Class:

```
class Service : public ThreadPoolImpl  
{
public:
int start();
}
int Service::start()
{
Create(); // as inherited from ThreadPoolImpl  
.......
}
```

The benefit is that now I can mock my Service class. But I am unable defined ThreadPoolImpl class

```
class ThreadPoolImpl : public InterfaceThreadPool
{
int Create () override;
}
int ThreadPoolImpl::Create()
{
//how can I call ThreadPool Create
}
```

Comment: Move `ThreadPool mThreadPool;` inside `ThreadPoolImpl` ?

Comment: Thanks is there any way apart from embedding the object?

Comment: ThreadPoolImpl should have access to `ThreadPool`. so alternative I saw are: by having one (and `Service` no longer has one), or accessing the one in `Service` (downcast), or passing it in argument of `Create`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually disagree with @Jarod42 comments. If you would like to test and mock both your `ThreadPool` class and `Service` class, the comfortable way is to design it like that:

```
class InterfaceThreadPool
{
public:
    virtual ~InterfaceThreadPool() = default;
    virtual int Create () = 0;
};

class ThreadPool : public InterfaceThreadPool
{
public:
    ~ThreadPool() override;
    int Create () override;
};

class IService
{
public:
    virtual ~IService() = default;
    virtual int start() = 0;
};

class Service: public IService
{
public:
    /*
     * InterfaceThreadPool might be passed by raw ptr, reference, smart ptr, whataver you like the most
     */
    Service(InterfaceThreadPool* mThreadPool);
    ~Service() override;
    int start() override { return mThreadPool_->Create(); }
private:
    InterfaceThreadPool* mThreadPool_;
};
```

Then in your production code you use the appropriate implementation of `Service` along with `ThreadPool`. In your tests you can use:

- `MockThreadPool` (derived from `InterfaceThreadPool`) to test `Service`
- `MockThreadPool` + `MockService` (derived from `IService`) to test some other things that need those two classes
- `MockService` + `ThreadPool` implementation invoked when `start` function is called (it's not very common, but maybe you can find it useful)

Comment: There is an issue in using MockService + ThreadPool cause the methods are not virtual in ThreadPool  and will invoke the original methods which is exactly not required during Mocking

Comment: Yes yes, I was rather thinking about something like: `EXPECT_CALL(mockService, start()).WillOnce(Invoke(&realThreadPool, &ThreadPool::Create))` But of course, it is not a very common practice.